# Sanity check for categorising arrivals in groups

Tags: clustering, dataset, interarrival-time

I have a question regarding the generation of arrival times. Assuming that I have an arrival rate of e.g. $400$ arrivals per hour. I would like to generate specific arrival times for e.g. $300$ arrivals. For this i would use an exponential distribution $Exp(1/400)$ and draw $300$ random arrivals.

However, after this I would like to categorise the arrivals into groups. I would like to group them into discrete time points of that hour e.g. $t=0$, $t=1$ etc. From the distribution I would have more arrivals in the beginning than in the end.

For example:

$Arrivals_t = [198, 85, 44 ...]$

My question is regarding the seperation into groups. I have though of two different ways to handle this.

1. Take the minimum and maximum arrival times and create equidistant sections. Assign each arrival to its group based on the sections.
2. Use K-medoids clustering.  Use clustering to generate the groups based solely on arrival times.

Question: Which methods seems to be more intuitive / correct to use in order to generate the groups. I have been thinking that the equidistant groups could result in a very fixed representation of the groups. The use of K-medoids seems a bit of an overkill, however it would allow for a more fluid representation of the groups.

Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share any details about a scenario you're trying to replicate? I would choose K-medoids for identifying arrival groups, versus equidistant intervals for time-specific partitions (maybe for determining a schedule for another event?). I am looking forward to the CV community experiences and advice on this

Comment: Yeah, I am generating a synthetic dataset in order to test an algorithm. It is a scheduling problem. The problem has to figure out which job to do based on the arrival times, profit etc. Therefore I need to generate a "release time" for the jobs. Based on the arrival times in would cluster them together to fin which jobs become release at time t=0, t=1 etc. Then the algorithm figures out which jobs are the best to perform and in which order.